# Как в aiogram3 сделать приветсвие нового участника чата?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram, aiogram-3.x

На данный момент есть такой код:

```
from aiogram import F, Router
from aiogram.types import Message


new_member_router = Router()

@new_member_router.chat_member(F.new_chat_member)


async def new_member(message: Message):
        
        await message.answer(f"<b>Hi!</b>" ,
                    parse_mode="HTML")
```

Но бот ничего не пишет в чат. Благодарю за любую помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спустя некоторое время удалось найти ответ.

```
from aiogram import F, Router, Bot
from aiogram.filters import IS_MEMBER, IS_NOT_MEMBER, ChatMemberUpdatedFilter
from aiogram.types import ChatMemberUpdated


new_member_router = Router()

@new_member_router.chat_member(ChatMemberUpdatedFilter(IS_NOT_MEMBER >> IS_MEMBER))
async def new_member(event: ChatMemberUpdated, bot: Bot):
        
        await event.answer(f"<b>Hi, {event.new_chat_member.user.first_name}!</b>",
                    parse_mode="HTML")
```

Но нужно указать, что хотите получать chat_member updates.
На вебхуках так:

```
async def on_startup(bot: Bot) -> None:
    await bot.set_webhook(f"{BASE_WEBHOOK_URL}{WEBHOOK_PATH}", 
                          secret_token=WEBHOOK_SECRET,
                          allowed_updates=["message", "chat_member"])
```

Надеюсь кому-то поможет.